# How to create a fullscreen gallery that covers the ENTIRE monitor?

Tags: javascript, gallery, fullscreen, monitor, cover

I'm starting out in web development so I know some HTML, CSS, JS and PH, and I need a photo gallery that has a button to go fullscreen and I need that fullscreen to COVER THE ENTIRE MONITOR, not just the browsers size. Do you know of any gallery with that functionality or could you help me in achiving this effect?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a [fullscreen API](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/fullscreen.html); support, however, is [less than perfect](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen), so if you insist on that, you might need a Flash-based solution instead.